# Pig : how to resample time series data?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, resampling, bigdata

I have a very large dataset that I am processing with `Pig`.

The data contains a `timestamp` (up to the second frequency), and I would like to aggregate my data at the minute frequency (counting how many observations per minnute, averaging other variables over that minute).

Is it possible to do that using `Pig`? 
Thanks!

Comment: you can create one more column that is a substring of upto minute and then group the relation using that column and then aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify you timestamp field (generate new field like YYYYmmddHHMMss to YYYYmmddHHMM), then group by timestamps and aggregate your data.